# PL/SQL how to return a User-Defined Record from create or replace function

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to learn PL/SQL
and I do not seem to understand how I can create a function and let it return a Record

I am trying to do something like this:

```
create or replace FUNCTION getMovie(movieID number)
RETURN record IS titleAndYear record(title varchar(100), production_Year number);
BEGIN
  if (titleAndYear is null) then
    titleAndYear:= MovieTitleAndYear('',0);
  end if;
  select TITLE ,YEAR into titleAndYear.title ,titleAndYear.production_Year from movie where MOVIE_ID = movieID;
  return titleAndYear;
END;
```

I know this is not working but I do not know why ?

**EDIT 1:**
I have also Tried this:

```
create or replace TYPE MovieTitleAndYear is OBJECT(title varchar(100), production_Year number);
/
create or replace FUNCTION getMovie(movieID number)
RETURN MovieTitleAndYear IS titleAndYear MovieTitleAndYear;
BEGIN
  if (titleAndYear is null) then
    titleAndYear:= MovieTitleAndYear('',0);
  end if;
  select TITLE ,YEAR into titleAndYear.title ,titleAndYear.production_Year from movie where MOVIE_ID = movieID;
  return titleAndYear;
END;
```

But then the result when i run this statement:

```
select 
GETMOVIE(
2540943 
) from dual;
```

becomes this

```
  GETMOVIE(2540943)
1 [DB_036.MOVIETITLEANDYEAR]
```

instead of two colums title and productionyear.

Comment: I'm Really stuck here any help even pointers would be greatly appriciated. I don't even know which direction or keywords I need to look at to solve this one.

Comment: Your 2nd approach is almost good. It returns the desired record but the result is just an object of PL/SQL type you declred.
You'd need to create a `PIPELINED` function to retrieve the result using `FROM TABLE()` clause in SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first example using a record won't work.  For a start, a function cannot return a value of a type that is only declared inside the function.  You can try moving the record type declaration to a package, but even if you then got the function to compile, running the query `select getMovie(2540943) from dual` would return an `ORA-00902 invalid datatype` error.

So I would recommend that you use a type instead.

If you are using a type, then to get the movie and year separately, you need to access the fields within the type individually, for example:

```
select getMovie(2540943).title, getMovie(2540943).production_year from dual
```

Alternatively, you can use a subquery if you want to avoid calling `getMovie()` twice:

```
select x.movie_info.title, x.movie_info.production_year from (select getMovie(2540943) as movie_info from dual) x;
```

Note that we need to use an alias for the subquery.  The following will give an `ORA-00904: "MOVIE_INFO"."PRODUCTION_YEAR": invalid identifier` error:

```
select movie_info.title, movie_info.production_year from (select getMovie(2540943) as movie_info from dual);
```

The problem here is that Oracle is looking for a table `movie_info` in the query, but it can't find one.  It doesn't realise that `movie_info` is actually a column.  If we introduce the alias `x`, Oracle then realises that `x.movie_info` is a column and so `x.movie_info.title` is a field within a type in the column.

Answer (score 1):

> Try this approach. I think your answer lies within this snippet. Let
>   me know if this helps.

```
--Create object type
CREATE OR REPLACE type av_obj_test
IS
  object
  (
    col1 VARCHAR2(100),
    col2 VARCHAR2(100) );


--C reate table type    
CREATE OR REPLACE type av_ntt_test
IS
  TABLE OF av_obj_test;


--Createfunction
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AV_RECORD RETURN 
AV_NTT_TEST
AS
av_record av_ntt_test;
BEGIN
NULL;
SELECT av_obj_test(LEVEL,'av'||LEVEL) BULK COLLECT INTO av_record FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10;
RETURN av_record;
END;


--Calling function
SELECT * FROM TABLE(AV_RECORD);

--------------------------------OUTPUT-------------------------------------

COL1    COL2
1       av1
2       av2
3       av3
4       av4
5       av5
6       av6
7       av7
8       av8
9       av9


-------------------------------OUTPUT----------------------------------------
```